# Iterate through elements using .call() with function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to run a function `calcItemTotal` on load that performs a simple calculation and updates the html of an element. The function uses `$(this)` so I use `.call()` to set the context.

The function needs to update every element of a particular class on load.

My approach is get all the elements of the class and then iterate through each based on how many there are, calling `calcItemTotal.call( Itotal[i] );` This sets the right context for `$(this)` for each element.

For clicked elements `calcItemTotal.call( this );` is working fine.

However it doesn't appear to work setting `.call( element[i] )`, what would be the right approach?

```
//update all item totals
$( window ).load(function() {

    //the totals
    var Itotal = document.querySelectorAll('.Itotal');

    //debugging = 12
    console.log('Itotal.length '+Itotal.length );

    //for each items total calculate and display total
    for (var i = 0; i < Itotal.length; ++i){

        //set what object called function (this)
        calcItemTotal.call( Itotal[i] );

        //debugging - this works correctly
        Itotal[i].style.color = 'red';

    };

    //update and display item total on click
    $(document).on('click' , '.item_add , .item_remove' , function() {  

        calcItemTotal.call( this ); //working

    });

});
```

Edit: added `calcItemTotal`

```
function calcItemTotal(){

    // strip all non numeric characters
    var selectedItem = 
    $(this).closest('.shopItem').find('.badge').text();

    //strip all non numeric characters except digits.
    var itemPrice = $(this).closest('.shopItem').find('.item_price').text();
    //convert integr to string > strip chars except digits and dots
    var priceStripped = itemPrice.toString().replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '');

    //item total
    var total = selectedItem * priceStripped;

    //rounded
    total = total.toFixed(2);

    //update element 
    $(this).closest('.shopItem').find('.Itotal').html('$'+total);

};
```

Comment: `$(this)` is not `this`. you might need to set `calcItemTotal.call( $(Itotal[i]) );` ?

Comment: Where is `calcItemTotal` function?

Comment: @Satpal added function

Comment: Code should work the problem is probably that it works with query selector `.item_add` or  `.item_remove` but it doesn't with query selector `.Itotal`. Probably because they have completely different parents.

Comment: Your code should probably work work if you do `var Itotal = document.querySelectorAll('.shopItem');` but to be sure we need the html

Comment: @HMR `.Itotal` is a child of `.shopItem` so that is ok as is. I can target the elements as I have tested by changing the style. Just cant loop with the call function. Does this look ok to you: `calcItemTotal.call( Itotal[i] );`

Comment: You should try to produce an example with some html showing the problem. Just looking at the code I can't see why it would not work.

Comment: Ok I have tested and it is indeed working however it is returning the value $0.00 meaning the function that populates `selectedItem` is yet to run. @hmr you led me down a path that confirmed that so thanks. Now just need to solve this problem..

Answer (score 0):

when your function `calcItemTotal.call( $(this) );` needs the jQuery `$(this)`.

You will need to give it so to your function.

```
  //set what object called function (this)
  calcItemTotal.call( $(Itotal[i]) );
```

but as it seems `call()` is vanilla JS and might just can handle the normal `this`.

Comment: `this` works in the context of a clicked element `calcItemTotal.call( this )` though? Gave your suggestion a shot but no change. Have added the function for clarity.